# 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, aiogram

Только начал изучать aiogram, не подскажите, что за ошибка и почему?

Ошибка:
@dp.message_handler(isSubscriber(), commands=['start'] )

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

**main.py**

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from filters import isSubscriber
import config

API_TOKEN = config.TOKEN

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(isSubscriber(), commands=['start'] )
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):

    start_buttons = ['Получить доступ', 'Куда подписаться',' Инфо' ]

    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True)
    keyboard.add(*start_buttons)

    await message.reply('Привет, ' + str(message.from_user.full_name) + '.\nЧтобы получить доступ надо подписаться на каналы. ',reply_markup=keyboard)


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Куда подписаться'))
async def send_signals(message: types.message):
    await message.answer(config.channels)


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Получить доступ'))
async def send_signals(message: types.message):
    await message.answer("Works")
   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

**isSubscriber.py**

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter
import config
from main import bot, dp 
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler


class isSubscriber(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, message: types.Message):
        subscribed  = 0 

        for chat_id in config.chat_ids:
            sub = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id = chat_id, user_id = message.from_user.id)
            if sub.status != types.ChatMemberStatus.LEFT:
                subscribed += 1
            else:
                break 
        else:
            if subscribed == len(config.chat_ids):
                return True
            else: 
                markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, inline_keyboard=[[
                    InlineKeyboardButton(text= 'Телеграм чат', url = 'url')
                ]])

                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Подпишитесь на канал и повторите попытку', reply_markup= markup) 

                raise CancelHandler()
```

**init.py**

```
from .isSubscriber import isSubscriber

#Установка кастомных фильтров 

def setup(dp:Dispatcher):
    dp.filters_factory.bind(isSubscriber)
```

Comment: А можно все стек-трейс ошибки?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\piarbottg\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from filters import isSubscriber
  File "d:\Python\piarbottg\filters\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .isSubscriber import isSubscriber
  File "d:\Python\piarbottg\filters\isSubscriber.py", line 4, in <module>
    from main import bot, dp
  File "d:\Python\piarbottg\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    @dp.message_handler(isSubscriber(), commands=['start'] )
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажись у тебя неправильный импорт в мейне, попробуй так

```
from filters.isSubscriber import isSubscriber
```

UPD.
Тебе нужно создать отдельный файл с ботом и диспатчером. Примерно такой.
**app.py**

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
import config

API_TOKEN = config.TOKEN

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```

Мейн же у тебя станет таким

```
from aiogram import executor, types
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from filters import isSubscriber

import config
from app import bot, dp


@dp.message_handler(isSubscriber(), commands=['start'] )
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True).add(
        'Получить доступ', 'Куда подписаться',' Инфо')

    await message.reply(
        f'Привет, {message.from_user.full_name}.\nЧтобы получить доступ надо подписаться на каналы.', 
        reply_markup=markup)


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Куда подписаться'))
async def send_signals(message: types.message):
    await message.answer(config.channels)
```

Останется заменить импорт в
**isSubscriber.py**

```
from main import bot, dp
```

на

```
from app import bot, dp
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'isSubscriber' from partially initialized module 'filters.isSubscriber' (most likely 
due to a circular import) (d:\Python\piarbottg\filters\isSubscriber.py)

Comment: @StepanRyzhov Обновил ответ